# Como abrir janela JInternalFrame após login?

Tags: java, swing

Sou novo em java para desktop e estou fazendo um programa com `swing`, e gostaria de saber como fazer um `JInternalFrame` abrir após o login ser efetuado, segue o código para análise.

```
  if(usuarioText.getText().equals(objConexao.rs.getString("nome"))
                && senhaText.getText().equals(objConexao.rs.getString("senha"))){


 //CadastroForm é um JInternalFrame

            CadastroForm form = new CadastroForm();  
            form.setVisible(true);  
            dispose();  



        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "usuário invalido");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

O método dispose esta fazendo o frame invisível logo após fazer o mesmo visível.

A não ser que seja para outro frame, não saberia dizer com apenas esse código.

Mas para abrir após o login retornar true, segue um exemplo

```
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

    if (foiAutenticado()) {
        JInternalFrame jInternalFrame = new JInternalFrame();
        jInternalFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.add(jInternalFrame);
        try {
            jInternalFrame.setSelected(true); //indica o fóco nesse JInternalFrame
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário invalido");
    }
```

É claro que esse JFrame que passei é apenas para demonstração, faça o uso do qual estiver na aplicação.

Mais exemplos e explicações nesse link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html